# Разработка для TOR API

Tags: php

Добрый вечер.

Интересует, существует ли у проекта Tor API и есть ли документация и примеры использования.
Интересует, можно ли с помощью данных средств разработать что-то подобное: использовать цепочки, которые строит Tor браузер, для обращения к сайту. А потом обновлять эти цепочки, аналогично опции "Смена личности".
Можно использовать для накрутки с разных IP адресов. Ну это как пример.
Для начала можно реализовать подобное: создать сайт с кнопкой, к у которой нажатие будет считываться только с одного IP.

P.S. Подскажите, каких меток можно поставить.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант могу предложить следующее:

Создаешь [docker контейнеры (tor)](https://hub.docker.com/r/nagev/tor/) с различным диапазоном портов, подключаешься через `SOCKS5` и при необходимости перезапускаешь цепочки внутри или контейнер.

Пример. Делаем `scale` предположим из 100 контейнеров, как только отработал делаем обновление цепочки, итд.

Answer (score 0):

Можно менять ip и делать запрос снова. 
Для смены звена (ip) после аутентификации нужно послать:

```
signal NEWNYM
```

Примеров использования на официальном сайте не нашёл. Можете использовать такую функцию:

```
$config = array(
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => 9050,
    'controlPort' => 9051,
    'controlPass' => 'pass',
);

function setTorNewIp(array $config) {
    $fp = @fsockopen(
        $config['host'],
        $config['controlPort'],
        $errno,
        $errstr,
        10
    );
    if (!$fp) {
        // Error: can not connect to TOR control port
        return false;
    }

    fputs($fp, "AUTHENTICATE \"{$config['controlPass']}\"\r\n");
    $response = fread($fp, 1024);
    list($code, $message) = explode(' ', $response, 2);
    if ($code != '250') {
        // Error: can not authenticate to TOR control port
        return false;
    }

    // запрос на смену звена
    fputs($fp, "signal NEWNYM\r\n");
    $response = fread($fp, 1024);
    list($code, $message) = explode(' ', $response, 2);
    if ($code != '250') {
        // Error: TOR ip has not been changed
        return false;
    }

    fclose($fp);

    return true;
}
```